# Magento CMS page to display files inside one folder

Tags: php, magento

Hello I have searched all day and found nothing, there are many scripts to display files in FTP server but I have folder with files in the same server than Magento.

I like the way Directory Listing Script from Evoluted.net http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script works but I haven't found a way to make it work in Magento CMS page.

I have a sub directory in Magento root folder named usermanuals and I upload different user manuals to the FTP folder and I would like them to automatically show up in my CMS page "User Manuals".

I have tried to use the Directory Listing Script in different ways but when the scrip is inside Magento .phtml template it will display all the content in

```
/htdocs/app/design/frontend/default/template
```

when it's inside

```
/htdocs/usermanuals
```

i can't find a way to call it out like this.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="dirshow.phml"}}
```

If i change it to php file it works fine as a standalone http://mydomain.com/usermanuals/dirshow.php showing just the content I need but then it's not inside Magento

Maybe someone can help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Copy back the content from `dirlistingv3/index.php` to `dirshow.phml`

You need to hard code the path to the user manuals folder, by default it will list content in the folder that contain the php script, so that why it is displaying the content of your template folder

> $startdir = '/htdocs/usermanuals/'

```
/*
  Include URL - If you are including this script in another file, 
  please define the URL to the Directory Listing script (relative
  from the host)
*/
$includeurl = false;

/*
  Start Directory - To list the files contained within the current 
  directory enter '.', otherwise enter the path to the directory 
  you wish to list. The path must be relative to the current 
  directory and cannot be above the location of index.php within the 
  directory structure.
*/
$startdir = '.';
```

***You could also do***

```
$startdir = $this->geData('path');
```

Then in your cms

```
{{block type="core/template" path="/htdocs/usermanuals/" template="dirshow.phml"}}
```

Comment: I tried both versions but didn't work and I belive **The path must be relative to the current 
directory and cannot be above the location of index.php within the 
directory structure.**  is creating the problem because the directory I would like to display is above the index.php file in my case dirshow.phml

Comment: Assuming that you have the correct permissions, your could try `../`